# Meaning of "in" in the phrase "In evaluating your progress..."

Tags: meaning-in-context

I think **in** is correctly used in the following sentence

> **In** evaluating your progress I have taken into account your classroom performance, your receptivity and how you have improved.

Because **in** means **while doing something**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are absolutely correct. The sentence could be rephrased as:

> While I was evaluating your progress, I took into account your
>   classroom performance, your receptivity...

I can't think of any important distinction between the two sentences, although perhaps the one you wrote is more formal.